# Printing the contents of a div using a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I am trying to generate an image out of the contents of a div. Unfortunately it is not working for me. The reason why I want to do that is because I want to send the generated image to a printer as a base64 string.

Anyway, below is my code:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = "data:image/svg+xml," +
               "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='300' height='250'>" +
                 "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                   document.getElementById('receipt_wrapper').innerHTML +
                 "</foreignObject>" +
               "</svg>";
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = data;
    img.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); };

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var imgBase64 = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    if (window.Android != undefined) {
        Android.print(image);
    }
```

Nothing is showing up in the canvas. What is wrong with my code?

P.S: I'm running this code inside an Android device.

Answer (score 2):

**That method no longer works on modern browsers.**

Using svg's `foreignObject` to capture webpage content is no longer allowed because of cross-domain security implemented by modern browsers.

If your receipt is simple html and does not include cross domain images you might take a look at html2canvas for content capturing on the client-side:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Alternatively, you could also use a "headless browser" like phantomJS if you want to capture webpage content on the server:

http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Yeah I tried `html2canvas` before but I kept getting this error: `IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount`. Unfortunately, I've just tried again, and I am getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: html2canvas works for simple html but often gets glitchy for anything greater than simple styling. If you've given html2canvas 2 shots...I'd abandon it. Have you looked at phantomJS.  It works on the server but it uses a full WebKit engine so your more complex html & CSS will be properly converted into image format.  Since you're printing you might alternately consider coding your receipt in .pdf format.

Comment: Well I found out what the problem is. Apparently the `bounds` of the `div` element I'm trying to render as an image are being returned as zeros using the method `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`. The content of the `div` is a table with some rows and two columns. Do you think I could do something to fix it?

Comment: And by the way, using the server is not an option. This should run on the client of a mobile device that is offline most of the time.